# SwiftUI closure errors

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, realm-mobile-platform, xcode-organizer

In my app store app the most seen error its this one:

```
0x00000001040f5248 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #4 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in LoginView.body.getter + 1924
1   MyApp                       0x00000001040f4b5c closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #4 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in LoginView.body.getter + 152
2   MyApp                       0x00000001040f7714 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in LoginView.loginWithFacebook() + 92
3   MyApp                       0x00000001040e61b8 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed SharedUserInfo?) -> () + 52 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   shared                          0x0000000105fa0c18 invokeFunction1V + 208
5   shared                          0x0000000105f70538 kfun:CommonFlow.$watch$lambda$0COROUTINE$58.invokeSuspend#internal + 348 (Utils.kt:17)
6   shared                          0x0000000105f706c8 kfun:CommonFlow.$watch$lambda$0COROUTINE$58.invoke#internal + 196 (Utils.kt:16)
7   shared                          0x0000000105c7ad48 <inlined-out:<anonymous>> + 208 (Transform.kt:73)
8   shared                          0x0000000105c7ad48 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.object-7.$collect$lambda$0COROUTINE$317.invokeSuspend#internal + 436 (Transform.kt:54)
9   shared                          0x0000000105c7af60 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.object-7.collect$lambda$0#internal + 120 (Emitters.kt:51)
10  shared                          0x0000000105c7af60 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.object-7.$collect$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$555.emit#internal + 196 (Transform.kt:52)
11  shared                          0x0000000105f629b0 kfun:com.app.MyApp.RealmRepo.object-1.collect$lambda$0#internal + 436 (Emitters.kt:49)
12  shared                          0x0000000105f629b0 kfun:com.app.MyApp.RealmRepo.object-1.$collect$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$227.emit#internal + 528 (RealmRepo.kt:53)
```

The loginWithFacebook methods calls another nested methods.

My question is how I am able to check in which line of code or at least in what method the error occurs?

Can I Symbolicate further that from my Xcode Organizer?

How can I know where the error occurs from the call stack?

I am not able to reproduce the same error.

Comment: 152 is the line that is marked

Comment: @loremipsum – Isn’t that the byte offset? Consider an example from [Understanding Crashes and Crash Logs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/?time=945), in a crash log that says “com.cookies.RecipeKit 0x0000000102213cff Recipe.image() + 415 (RecipeImage.swift:26)”, 415 is the byte offset and 26 is line number, right?